# Calculating time difference and returning result in hours

Tags: python, pandas

I have calculated the time delta between two columns and would like to convert that to hours.

I have tried extracting the timedelta as hours ie:

```
df_clean['data__answered_at'] - df_clean['user_entered_details_stage_timestamp__c'].dt.hour
```

but this doesn't seem to work/returns an error message.

Here is a sample of the output of the time delta calculation:

```
628         1 days 23:22:26
806         1 days 18:33:41
708         0 days 00:12:00
592         0 days 01:14:35
709         0 days 00:16:45
295      -81 days +09:45:03
1001        0 days 02:46:02
817         0 days 02:46:52
593         0 days 03:57:11
807         0 days 05:28:56
1069        0 days 10:22:24
464         0 days 00:00:36
1          11 days 14:35:31
243                     NaT
296                     NaT
819     -120 days +13:11:23
1002        0 days 00:10:43
65                      NaT
200         0 days 04:49:26
31          2 days 17:09:26
32        -1 days +17:31:12
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `np.timedelta64`:

Division will cast the column to that unit.

```
s/np.timedelta64(1, 'h')
0   -48.000000
1   -48.333333
2   -48.666667
3   -49.000000
4   -49.333333
5          NaN
dtype: float64
```

#### `DatetimeIndex.total_seconds()`

```
s.dt.total_seconds()/3600  # 3600 seconds in an hour
0   -48.000000
1   -48.333333
2   -48.666667
3   -49.000000
4   -49.333333
5          NaN
dtype: float64
```

---

#### Sample Data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': pd.date_range('2010-01-01', periods=6, freq='11min'),
                   'B': pd.date_range('2010-01-03', periods=6, freq='31min')})
df.iloc[-1,:] = pd.NaT
s = df.A-df.B

#0   -2 days +00:00:00
#1   -3 days +23:40:00
#2   -3 days +23:20:00
#3   -3 days +23:00:00
#4   -3 days +22:40:00
#5                 NaT
#dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do:

```
df['TD'] = (df_clean['data__answered_at'] - df_clean['user_entered_details_stage_timestamp__c']).astype('timedelta64[s]')
```

which will get you the difference in seconds. To convert from seconds to hours you can then just do some simple math:

```
df['TD'] = (df['TD']/60)/60
```

To get your timedelta in hours.